# Array Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, background-image

Pessoal gostaria de saber como buscar uma imagem ao invés de color nesse array javascript abaixo
Ao invés disso:

```
<script>
  array var arrDados = [{title: "Dados 1", value: 1, **color**: "#fe4400"}]
</script>
```

Queria alterar para buscar imagem, só que da forma abaixo não está correta:

```
<script>
    var arrDados = [ {title: "Dados 1", value: 1, background-image: "www.site.com.br/imagem/figura.png"}]
</script>
```

Onde está **color** desenho pegar uma imagem. Grato pela ajuda de vocês

Comment: Onde está a imagem?

Comment: eu quero que ao invés de color, o array puxe uma imagem do servidor. Por exemplo, var arrDados = [ {title: "Dados 1", value: 1, background-image: "www.site.com.br/imagem/figura.png" }. Só que dessa forma a imagem não é buscada. Qual seria a forma correta?

Comment: <script >var arrDados = [ {title: "Dados 1", value: 1, background-image: "www.site.com.br/imagem/figura.png" }]</script >

Comment: É bom editar a pergunta e colocar as informações.

Comment: Não entendi exatamente nada. Releia sua pergunta e veja se tem lógica. Nos informe mais, principalmente de onde você está recebendo as informações.

Comment: Eu só quero saber como altera de color para imagem nesse script: <script >var arrdados = [
  {title: "Dados 1", value: 1, color: "#fe4400" },
  {title: "Dados 2", value: 1, color: "#de4400" },
  {title: "Dados  3", value: 1, color: "#be4400" },
  {title: "Dados 4", value: 1, color: "#ce4400" }
]; alert (title','+value',' +color</script> pois utilizando background-image ao invés de color não funciona. Já tentei backgroundImage e também não funciona.

Comment: Olha eu tenho um pieChart que retorna em cor. Só que desejo inserir imagem ao invés de cor na pizza. Por exemplo, 55% é Corinthians e 45% é Palmeiras. Ao invés de cores, vem a camisa dos clubes na pizza

Comment: Dê uma olhada nesse modelo e veja se entende: https://codepen.io/maikonmatheus/pen/LVwPQV

Comment: Acho que isso só aceita cor, parece ser um svg.

Answer (score 0):

Se você quer adicionar `background-image`s num vetor que tem `color`s, pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
$.each(arrDados, function (i, o) {

    switch (o.color) {
        case '#fe4400':
            o['background-image'] = 'http://www.meusite.com.br/img/figura-do-fe4400.jpg';
            break;
        case '#de4400':
            o['background-image'] = 'http://www.meusite.com.br/img/figura-do-de4400.jpg';
            break;
        case ...
                                   ....
            break; 
    }
    o.color = undefined;

});
```

E caso sua pergunta seja referente ao Fiddle que disponibilizou [aqui](https://codepen.io/maikonmatheus/pen/LVwPQV), ele provavelmente não aceita imagens, por se tratar de imagem rasterizada.

Comment: Ok. Agradeço a todos aqui que me atenderam. Se tiver uma alternativa do exemplo que enviei no link, fico agradecido.